# SQL Remove Duplicate Rows of Data from Query Result

Tags: sql

I am still learning the ropes of SQL so I have run into my first obstacle. I am to create an SQL query that retrieves employee.firstname, employee.lastname, dependents.depname, and dependents.birthday from the two tables employees and dependents.
I am only supposed to show an employee if he or she has a dependent.

My primary table (employee; only the first 43 rows): [employee table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF3Wy.png)
My secondary table (dependents): [dependents table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Cash.png)

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    employee.firstname, employee.lastname, 
    dependents.depname, dependents.birthday
FROM 
    employee
INNER JOIN 
    dependents ON employee.id = dependents.empid
```

This works fine however I run into many duplicate rows of data:

[Original Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abrlO.png)

This is not the full query result but I think it provides sufficient evidence of my problem.

I used the DISTINCT keyword with my SELECT statement, but it only retrieved a small number of my dependents.

[Adding DISTINCT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t95xn.png)

Comment: can you please share the structure of both the tables

Comment: Try using `select *` to see what's going wrong. It appears to me that you have multiple employee rows with the same id. If not that then the dups must be in dependents. Using `distinct` is going to "correct" the issue while it masks a problem in the data.

Comment: Yes, view now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already any duplicates in one of the tables `employee` or `dependents`? The second result looks correct. With `select distinct` the database removes all duplicates from the result set.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The employee table given to us included duplicate rows of the same employees.